# identifier expected on this token error in forge mdk 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

in the while function, the it keeps saying this needs an Identifier

```
                                                     |
public void onEnable() {                             V
        while(ModuleManager.this.modules.new.Sprint.this.isToggled() == true) {
            if(Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.moveForward > 0) {
                Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.setSprinting(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what's happening, thanks if you can help.

Comment: The error occurres because 'this' is a keyword in java. It cannot be the property of any other class.

Comment: o, k, do you know a way I could reference the sprint? I used this.modules.add(new Sprint()); in the modManager.java file to add it.

Comment: If you don't have the specific instance you need nor any getters then I don't really know what to do. If you know that some other class holds a reference then you could try accessing it with reflection.